# Grammars && LL Parsers

Tags: grammar, ll-grammar

So I have a homework assignment and I've spent over 2hrs trying to find out why this grammar will not work with a LL parser:

```
<A> → a <B>
<A> → a b <C>
<B> → b d <D>
<C> → d <E>
<D> → m n
<E> → x y
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?  I know one of the ways an LL could get tripped up is if it runs into a infinite loop which I don't believe it does here.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the assignmet is why the grammar is not LL(**1**)?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that by LL Parser you mean LL(1) parser ( an LL Parser with lookahead of 1)

For a grammar to be parse-able by an LL(1) parser, it must be LL(1). There are a few things that a grammar must abide by to be LL(1), if it breaks one of these, it is called an LL(1) conflict.

- **FIRST/FIRST Conflict:**

  For every non-terminal, each production must have a disjoint FIRST set. (The FIRST set is the set of all terminals that can begin sentences derived from the subject.)

  E.G: In your example above, the non-terminal  has two productions:

  ```
  <A> -> a <B>
  <A> -> a b <C>
  ```

  The FIRST sets of each of the productions are as follows:

  ```
  FIRST(a <B>) = {a}
  FIRST(a b <C>) = {a}
  ```

  You can quite clearly see that these two sets intersect. This is a problem because in an LL parser, if a point is reached where A is on the stack, and the next symbol to be read is 'a', then the parser does not know whether to pick `<A> -> a <B>` or `<A> -> a b <C>`.
- **FIRST/FOLLOW Conflict:**

  This occurs when, for a particular non-terminal `A`; `FOLLOW(A)` and `FIRST(A)` intersect and `A` is `NULLABLE`. This particular conflict does not arise in your example.

For more details on FIRST, FOLLOW and NULLABLE, i would

For more details on these conflicts, and for some examples, see [the Wikipedia page on LL(1) Conflicts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#LL.281.29_Conflicts).